# Views in my GridLayout aren't on a single row

Tags: android, xml, grid-layout

I have an xml file for creating a fragment.In this fragment I have 8 views like this:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <Button
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="72sp"
        tools:text="A" />

    <Button
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        tools:text="+" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/textViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        tools:text="-" />

    <Button
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        tools:text="+" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/textViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        tools:text="-" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/textViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:layout_column="3" />

</GridLayout>
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

Why aren't these elements in one line? What is my mistake? In the styles I've just set the margins and background and text size. I've tried to change the width and height of the layout to match parent but result still same.

Comment: I don't know the reson. But if I add `android:layout_gravity="top"` to the last TextView, it moves up and align with other views. Hope that helps!

Comment: I test layout_gravity to center and also bottom I got the same result. thank you